# How to encrypt data in browser with JavaScript and decrypt on server side with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt a message using AES256 on the browser, send it to the server, and then decrypt it but I keep getting this error server-side :

`error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt`

I tried for hours to find a solution but I don't see where is the issue. I'm using [crypto-js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) for client-side and the standard library for Node.js `crypto`

This is the code sample that I'm using on client-side.

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

const secret = 'example';
const passphrase = 'secret-passphrase'

const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(secret, passphrase);
const encrypted64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted.ciphertext);

// make a request to a Node.js API with the password encrypted
```

This is the code sample that I'm using on server-side.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const secret = req.body.secret;

const passphrase = 'secret-passphrase'
const decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes256', passphrase);

let decrypted = decipher.update(secret, 'base64', 'utf8');
decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you use https?

Comment: As @James wrote, if you run your site over HTTPS all the traffic is already encrypted, and with letsencrypt issuing free Certs, there isn't really a reason to use HTTP

Comment: @James I'm already using `HTTPS` protocol.

Comment: Then why would you want additional encryption? It doesn't really make anything safer

Comment: @Luca I understand and you are right. I can rely on the HTTPS. For my personal knowledge, do you have an idea on this issue?

Comment: No, I have never encountered this issue nor have I ever used crypto-js, that's why I didn't post my comment as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Using HTTPS will encrypt the payload during the transfer and have it decrypted at the server. HTTPS uses RSA to encrypt the keys used in the encryption of the message.
RSA uses 1024 bit key value which is difficult to crack. The hacker has to factor large numbers into their original prime values to get the keys which makes its almost impossible to crack.

It is generally advisable to use HTTPS in your transmissions.

Answer (score 1):

The error generally occurs when you use the wrong `key`.

You are using different packages to begin with.
`crypto-js` will take your passphrase, create a key and encrypt cleartext that you have in `secret`.
`crypto` will do the same when you create Decipher, but then there's the issue of padding. In short, `key` is not same for `crypto` when decrypting.

Use a 32 bytes key like `abcabcabc1abcabcabc1abcabcabc132`

Go for client-side encryption like:

```
var ciphertext= C.AES.encrypt(secret, C.enc.Hex.parse(passphrase), { mode: C.mode.ECB, padding: C.pad.NoPadding }).ciphertext.toString();
```

And on your server side code go for following (after passing the same passphrase to `decipher`):

```
let decrypted = decipher.update(ciphertext, 'hex', 'utf8');
```

Give it a try. It should work. It will be easier if you use `crypto-js` on both client and server.

Hope it helps!